# C# Surface Pro 4 Camera

Tags: c#, wpf

I am developing a WPF program in visual studio 2013.
This program will be installed on MS Surface Pro 4's , one part of the application required to take an snap photo from the front camera.

I would like to place a button in my WPF program that will open the surface Pro 4 camera and take a picture. Does any one know how to accomplish this?
or if there are an DLL you can use for the camera.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Open Windows 8.1 "Camera app" with VBA](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28036527/open-windows-8-1-camera-app-with-vba)

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2881858/how-to-get-web-cam-images-in-c

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get web cam images in C#?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2881858/how-to-get-web-cam-images-in-c)

Answer (score 1):

To use the native Windows camera "app" to capture an image you can make use of [`Windows.Media.Capture.CameraCaptureUI`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/br241030):

```
CameraCaptureUI captureUI = new CameraCaptureUI();
captureUI.PhotoSettings.Format = CameraCaptureUIPhotoFormat.Jpeg;
captureUI.PhotoSettings.CroppedSizeInPixels = new Size(200, 200); 

StorageFile photo = await captureUI.CaptureFileAsync(CameraCaptureUIMode.Photo);
```

This will save the image to a location within your app's local storage where can you process as required.

See the following Microsoft article for more details: [Capture photos and video with Windows built-in camera UI](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows/uwp/audio-video-camera/capture-photos-and-video-with-cameracaptureui)

Comment: The question is about WPF, not UWP.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by using Emgu CV and WPF: http://www.emgu.com/wiki/index.php/Main_Page